# Chrome App not launching when published

Tags: google-chrome-app

I've created a Chrome app which, when I load locally works fine. However, when I publish it to the Chrome App store and install I get a 404 that it couldn't find `index.html`. Really lost at this point. Here's the `app` section of my `manifest.json`:

```
"app": {
  "launch": {
    "local_path": "index.html"
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the unpacked version of the Chrome app in the Extensions directory

[[User Data Directory](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory)]/[Profile Dir (likely named 'Default')]/Extensions/aaaaaaaaaaaahashkeyzzzzzzzzzz

Try

1. Loading an unpackaged app from that installed directory.
2. Examining the files, is index.html missing, or file permissions set incorrectly?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like the index.html file is missing from the zip archive, or in a different place to the manifest.